# Ajaxtoolkit controls are unable to access in my web application

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, web, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am unable to use `Ajaxtoolkit` controls in my program even after adding reference in my project and having ajax toolkit controls in my toolkit!

I added:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
```

...in my `ASP.NET` page. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add toolkit script manager control from ajax control toolkit in your page.